# Non-blocking channel in go

Tags: go, nonblocking, channel, goroutine

I have some code like this:

```
go func(ch chan bool) chan bool {

    // some processing
    ch <- true
    return ch
}(ch)

for i := 0; i < TotalQuestions; i++ {
    // check if channel ch has some value
    // If it has then execute below statements, else break out of the loop


    fmt.Println(questions[i])
    answer, _ := InputReader.ReadString('\n')

    // some processing

}
fmt.Println("Your Total score is " + strconv.Itoa(TotalScore) + " out of " + strconv.Itoa(TotalQuestions))
```

Now what I want to do is to check if channel ch has a value (in for loop). If it has a value then I want to break out of the for loop to print the last statement. otherwise, I want to continue my loop. I tried to insert select block but that didn't work (The channel got blocked and code didn't print questions). How to do that?

Comment: why were you using channel, why can't use a boolean variable or something? If you are sending something through channel, once the receiver receives it, it will not exist anymore, are you sure you want it this way, because then a normal boolean would suffice.

Comment: While this is possible with buffered channels, there is an inherent race involved doing that. This is a design smell, most likely an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You shouldn't use channels like this, most likely you shouldn't use channels at all for what you want to do. What is it you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to make a quiz program with a timer. When timer expires or user answers every question the program should stop and print the score. While I was at it, I tried channels for learning.

Comment: A select statement would do the trick. Use the channel on one case, the other is a condition on the quizz (all questions answered). This inside a (infinite) for loop, will stop the program only if the timer is done, or all the questions are answered.

Comment: the question is not a good fit for that title. Better examples could exist for that question so that googlers get better help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```golang
package main
    
import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    // user score, no.of questions asked so far
    var score, num int
    var correct bool // temporary variable to decide if the answer is right
    // questions
    var questions = make([]string, 13)

    t1 := time.Tick(time.Second * 7) // timer loop:
    for {
        select {
        case <-t1:
            log.Println("ran out of time")
            break loop
        default:
            // have any questions further questions to ask
            if num < len(questions) {

                // simulate typing
                time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 777)

                // correct or wrong answer
                correct = (rand.Intn(777)%2 == 0)

                if correct {
                    fmt.Println("you did it")
                    score++ //increase score
                } else {
                    fmt.Println("try again")
                }

            } else {
                // no questions, state and break
                log.Println("all questions were finished")
                break loop //break loop, all questions were finished
            }
            num++
        }
    }

    //print final score
    fmt.Println("your score is:", score)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Functional way of reading from a channel in a non-blocking manner:

```
func CollectChanOne[T any](ch <-chan T) (T, bool) {
    select {
    case val, stillOpen := <-ch:
        return val, stillOpen
    default:
        var zeroT T
        return zeroT, false
    }
}
```

Example: https://go.dev/play/p/Njwyt32B4oT

N.B. This example also have another method CollectChanRemaining() which reads all buffered elements in the channel.